# Can meat flavored tomato sauce be used without heating?

Tags: food-safety, pasta, tomatoes, canning, ground-beef

I saw similar questions but I can't comment as I'm new.
Is there any tomato sauce with meat chunks? Can those be used without cooking?

Comment: Always check the label of the product you buy.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Favour returned, question upvoted!  The simplest questions with the simplest answers are the most satisfying on this site!  **:-)**

Comment: Thanks! I cannot upvote now as I am new but will do so as well for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, you can buy tomato sauce with meat chunks around here
- Yes they're safe to eat cold